# how to run old code where print is used as keyword with python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, keyword

I know that in python 3 the keyword print became a function.
But is it possible to reuse my old code without replacing every

```
print "Error text"
```

by:

```
print("Error text")
```

per hand?

Comment: No, but you can use tools which help with this replacement like `2to3`.

Comment: You could write a Python script to apply regex based substitution on your old Python files...

Comment: For info on using 2to3 check out https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html

Comment: No, you cannot use the Python 3 interpreter on Python 2 syntax. Python 3 *explicitly breaks backwards compatibility*.

Comment: 2to3 is included with the py3 distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to read about [Automated Python 2 to 3 code translation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) and see if it can be useful to you or not ?